# Copy and paste in original form

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

In Mathematica 10, after I copy an expression that contains subscripts and fractions the pasted result is always reverted into input form such as Subscript[a,1]. How do I change this default setting so that it is pasting in the same form as it was copied?

Edit: I read other similar posts but those require pressing extra keys such as Ctrl+Shift+N. There should be a setting to change the default paste option into a new cell in the same notebook. In Mathematica 8 there wasn't any change to pasted expressions.

Comment: Provided you paste your expression into a cell like Formula or FormulaNumbered, or into an inline cell. The latter is the one you obtain by placing cursor into the text line and pressing Ctrl+9. Try the following: select your expression, go to Menu/Evaluation and press Evaluate in Place. Done.

Comment: Where are you pasting to? The answer depends on that.

Comment: I am trying to paste expressions into a new cell in the same notebook. I wonder if there is a hidden setting that can be changed to choose default paste option.